# sitemap empty and can't upload on Google Webmaster

Tags: xml

I got some trouble this day. I wanna reference (SEO) my website on Google so I try to create a Sitemap.xml first, I generated on a webSite called "www.xml-sitemaps.com" I was surprised cause the file was empty. here is a look of my xml files

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<!--
 created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com 
-->
</urlset>
```

can anyone help me cause after that when I try to upload on webmaster it shows me that it miss a HTML Tag.

Comment: <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<!--
 created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com 
-->
</urlset>

Comment: Please edit your question with the code instead of in a comment.

Comment: Sorry. This is my question and the code instead of add code in the comment below